# Canonical topology on standard groups?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology

I just wanted to know whether there is any standard topology on groups like $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ ? - The only one that I could imagine, especially for finite groups is the discrete topology. Would you agree that the discrete topology is the standard one in the context of covering maps and so on?

EDIT: It was suggested in the comments that this is true, so I would also be interested in the question: Does the discrete topology always mean include that the group is a topological one? -I actually think that this is true.

Comment: Do you require that the topology turns the group into a topological group?

Comment: If there's no obvious topology, the group is usually given the discrete topology yes.

Comment: [Topological groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group) impose continuity of the group operation (and commonly on group actions if applicable).  This previous Math.SE Question, [Covering of a topological group is a topological group](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/5391/3111), may be of interest.

Comment: What is the topology induced by the metric on the cayley graph out of interest?

Comment: @JC574: Since the Cayley graph metric evaluated on pairs of vertices always has values in the non-negative integers, the radius $1/2$ open ball in the group around any element consists solely of that element. So the topology on the group is discrete.

Comment: cool, thanks. should have just thought about it really haha

Comment: @FPE actually no, but aren't both groups topological groups with the discrete topology?

Comment: Why would you put a topology on a group that has nothing to do with the group structure? Anyway, a finite topological group is always discrete "mod $N$" where $N$ is the closure of the identity, a normal subgroup. [See here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216557/why-isnt-there-interest-in-nontrivial-nondiscrete-topologies-on-finite-groups). We can also regard $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z$ as subgroups of $S^1$ and $\Bbb R$ respectively, and as subspaces they are discrete. Usually the "standard topology" is determined by context and established historical precedent.

Comment: @blue thank you, i see.